# Different action on submit a form depending on input value

Tags: html, forms

I have a basic html form with a search box. depnding if the user inputs searchA or searchA-B, I need to redirect him to two different places (url is formatted differently).

How would you suggest I do that?

```
<form name="ajaxSearchFrm" action="url1 or url2 depending on the value of searchText" method="GET">
        <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" style="width:200px;" onKeyUp="searchSuggest();" autocomplete="off">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" value="Search" style="background-color: #fff; font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica; color: black; font-size: 10px;" />
        <div id="formSuggestLayer"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use javascript to evaluate the contents of the text box. Depending on the value, change the action of the form then submit the form via javascript. You'll have to change your submit button to a regular button with an onClick event though.

JavaScript:

```
function EvaluateForm()
{
    if( document.getElementById('searchText').value == 'A' ){
        //submit to A
        document.ajaxSearchFrm.action = "myurlA.com";
    }
    else{
        //submit to b
        document.ajaxSearchFrm.action = "myurlB.com";
    }
    document.forms["ajaxSearchFrm"].submit();

    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="ajaxSearchFrm" action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="searchText" name="searchText" style="width:200px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="return EvaluateForm();" />
    <div id="formSuggestLayer"></div>
</form>
```